# How can i change the font size of the checkbox Name

Tags: python, pyqt4, qcombobox, qcheckbox

Here is my code, i want to change font size of the checkbox name and increase the boarded size of the comboBOx, i tried like this but i am not getting the output properly.Can you please guide me how to change the size of the font

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        cb = QtGui.QCheckBox('Show title', self)
        cb.move(20, 20)
        cb.toggle()
        frequencycb = QtGui.QComboBox()
        frequencycb.addItems(["30KHZ", "60KHZ","120KHZ","300KHZ","0.6MHZ", "1.2MHZ","3MHZ","6MHZ"])
        vbox.addWidget(cb)
        vbox.addWidget(frequencycb)
        self.setLayout(vbox)


        cb.stateChanged.connect(self.changeTitle)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('QtGui.QCheckBox')
        self.show()

    def changeTitle(self, state):

        if state == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.setWindowTitle('QtGui.QCheckBox')
        else:
            self.setWindowTitle('')

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: try with: `self.interpolate2.setFont(self.frequencycb.font())`

Comment: no its not working

Comment: you could provide a [mcve], I think you are using QSS in another part that is affecting.

Comment: no i am not using anything,i used here vertical layout for that i added combobox and checkbox that it

Comment: for increasing the font i used here self.interpolate2.setStyleSheet("QCheckBox::indicator { width:50px; height: 50px; }"); this code is not used for me

Comment: please provide a [mcve], I guess it's easy to do it, why do not you do it? :-)

Comment: i  edit my code once please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I have PyQt5
Try it:

```
import sys
#from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5 import Qt

class Example(Qt.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        vbox = Qt.QVBoxLayout()
        cb = Qt.QCheckBox('Show title', self)
        cb.move(20, 20)
        cb.toggle()
        frequencycb = Qt.QComboBox()
        frequencycb.addItems(["30KHZ", "60KHZ","120KHZ","300KHZ","0.6MHZ", "1.2MHZ","3MHZ","6MHZ"])
        vbox.addWidget(cb)
        vbox.addWidget(frequencycb)
        self.setLayout(vbox)


        cb.stateChanged.connect(self.changeTitle)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('QtGui.QCheckBox')
        self.show()

    def changeTitle(self, state):
        if state == Qt.Qt.Checked:
            self.setWindowTitle('QtGui.QCheckBox')
        else:
            self.setWindowTitle('')


StyleSheet = '''
QCheckBox {
    spacing: 5px;
    font-size:25px;     /* <--- */
}

QCheckBox::indicator {
    width:  33px;
    height: 33px;
}
'''            

def main():

    app = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)

    app.setStyle("fusion")                 # +++
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)

    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: i want to change chekbox name i.e show title font size

Comment: @raghava  I changed the example